# Window.reset() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, window, reload, reset

Can someone explain how window.reset works in Java script.

I have a quiz with 5 part quizees. All of the part quizzes is built in 1 html page. So when you push NEXT Button the wrapper change Nd show the next quiz with the help of classList.add/remove(hide) where hide is display:none in CSS.

Now I want to use window.reset() in the console to reset a quiz at anytime.
So for exemple, if I'am in the middle of quiz 4 I want to be able to write window.reset() in the console and the 4th quiz starts again and reset the points.

But I dont understand how I go about it.
Every test is in its own module. Cant show any code cause its so complex and alot of code.

Hope someone can give me a good advice, even though its a very complex question

Comment: It should be `form.reset()` to reset the inputs in the form to their default values.

Comment: formReference.reset() is not going to do anything with your javascript code. It just resets the form values.